# Files become read-only when adding files to a Samba share between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

I'm very green with Linux/Ubuntu in general so please forgive me.

I'm trying to setup a shared network folder so I can copy over files from my Windows PC without needing to use a physical drive. I used Samba to create a shared directory and was able to link to it on my PC. I made sure all the permissions were correct for the shared folder. The problem now is I can only add files to the shared directory. Any files created within are read-only, which defeats the whole purpose. What do I need to do to make sure everything within the shared directory has the same permissions?

Comment: To be clear, you can *write* files to the Samba share on Ubuntu, but cannot read the files back to your Windows machine(s). Is this correct? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? How was the Samba share configured?

Comment: @matigo I'll try to answer your questions as best I can but I might be misunderstanding. While in Ubuntu I can access everything with full permissions, but when using the windows machine I can only write to the first folder, any deeper and it becomes read only. The Samba share was configured as default, but in "Local Network Share" settings I checked both boxes trying to allow full permissions.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  For example *"I made sure all the permissions were correct"* - what actions did you take exactly?  It's best if you recount all steps in a reproducible way so we can understand exactly what you did when you set up the share. A potential problem is that Windows and Ubuntu handle ownership and permissions very differently. Windows has no concept of the POSIX permissions and ownership that are used by file systems used by Ubuntu. It's possible that when you "made sure permissions were correct", you did something you didn't need to do which resulted in this problem.

Comment: Please be specific, what OS & release are you using, if you're using command, what command you're getting and the exact error message you get you're asking about (a read-only file-system is a very different error to a directory that is read-only and your description isn't clear enough as to which read-only message(s) you're getting).

Answer (score 0):

> While in Ubuntu I can access everything with full permissions, but
> when using the windows machine I can only write to the first folder,
> any deeper and it becomes read only. The Samba share was configured as
> default, but in "Local Network Share" settings I checked both boxes
> trying to allow full permissions.

So you created a samba usershare allowing full access to the share to everyone. The usershare process ( Local Network Share ) enables that by setting Linux permissions to the folder being shared so that it is writeable to everyone.

But not to the folders underneath. If you created on the Ubuntu machine a folder within that shared folder as user brady for example it will have Linux permissions of 755. The samba client can write to the parent folder but not to the subfolder.

Since you are using the "Local Network Share" process what you could do is:

** Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf

** Right under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line add this one:

```
force user = brady
```

*Change `brady` to your actual Ubuntu login user name.*

** Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

The samba client will be viewed as brady for these shares so if brady on the Ubuntu machine itself has full access so will the samba client on the Windows machine.